# Reference Child Panels in GAS SplitLayoutPanel or DockPanel

Tags: google-apps-script

After Creating a SplitLayoutPanel in Google Apps Script
How do you target a specific panel from subsequent functions/handlers.
For instance, if you create a Split Panel with a "Menu" on top ("North") of the Dragger/Splitter bar, and a "View" area on below the bar.....
(1) Is it possible reference a specific panel to clear/add more items.
(2) For Example Is it possible to "clear()" only the North Panel?

CREATE THE SPLIT PANEL

```
function doGet()
{
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var splitPanel = app.createSplitLayoutPanel();
  splitPanel.setId("HOMEPAGE");
  splitPanel.addNorth(app.createLabel('Menu Area'), 25);
  splitPanel.add(app.createLabel('View Area'));
  splitPanel.setHeight('100%').setWidth('100%');
  app.add(splitPanel);
  return  app;
}


function clearMenuBar()
{
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var splitPanel = app.getElementById("HOMEPAGE");
  splitPanel[0].clear(); // IS THERE A WAY TO REFERENCE A SPECIFIC PANEL? 
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working hard on this type of panel and i apreciated that it has a lot of problems with references.

If you have created an area (child Panel) with a Label for ex:

`var lbContent = app.createLabel().setText("HOME").setId("lbContent ");`

you can edit it in action button with:

`var lbContent = app.getElementById("lbContent");`

`lbContent.setText("PAGE 1 ");`

And it works!

**I hope it helps you!**

Comment: i am testing and i think only works edit lables but i have created a verticalPanel to add it into the splitlayoutPanel  and always get error.

Comment: I tryed to add the new verticalPanel in the same panel where i have the label which i can edit text but error ocurred!!

Comment: This panel really needs many improvements, or someone to tell us how to make references to widgets